# MVC5 Adding Root Namespaces to Views web.config, builds without error, but errors in intellisense and Runtime

Tags: c#, namespaces, web-config, intellisense, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've probably missed an important nugget of information somewhere here, however I wonder if someone could correct my understanding or at least confirm I've not lost my beans.

I have an MVC5 website project, all set up nicely. My applications root namespace is `MyApp` for examples sake.

I have some `MyApp.Properties` and `MyApp.Models` of course and onwards, all standard. Now in my Views folder my `web.config` is declared as so (extract) :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyApp" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <!-- ... other standard config ... -->
<configuration>
```

Which all makes sense, however in my view I want to declare my applicationSettings (`Settings`) which is itself in the `MyApp.Properties` namespace (note, I've also tested this with a basic class in `MyApp.Models` for sense checking). I can declare this like so :

```
@using MyApp.Properties
@{ Settings appSettings = new Settings(); }
```

Compiles fine, intellisense fine

```
@{ MyApp.Properies.Settings appSettings = new MyApp.Properies.Settings(); }
```

Compiles fine, intellisense fine

So thats nice, however I already have my root namespace included inthe web.config, so my assumption is that I can do this :

```
@{ Properties.Settings appSettings = new Properties.Settings(); }
```

This builds absolutely fine (no errors), however intellisense red underlines `Properties.Settings` and on page view I get a "Compilation Error" with the message :

> The type or namespace name 'Properties' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Wierdly, if I add `MyApp.Properties` to the Web.config, I can declare my settings as expected with a simple `@{ Settings appSettings = new Settings(); }`, likewise if I add `@using MyApp` or `@using MyApp.Properties` the relevent code works fine too (as expected).

So my question is, **What gives with the root namespace? Why can't I use it in my Web.config?? If this is a bone-fide rule (don't use the root namespace) where is it documented so I can teach myself a lesson???**

Many thanks in advance guru's!!

Comment: Well, I assume it's not just me having a mind melt moment then due to the lack of "you idiot!" replies! Can anybody even confirm what I'm on about here, even an opinion on if root namespaces should ever be included...